# Compare & combine two columns in xlsx file nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-modules, xlsx

I have a scenario where I have two xlsx files in which I have only one column in common ("colab") in both xlsx files.
I want to read both the xlsx files then compare the common column("colab") and combine both of them into another new one according to order.

Note : "colab" value will never be null.

I tried working with this module named https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-compare but it did not work, As I am quite new to nodejs can somebody help me here on how to resolve this

code below outputs nothing but empty array

```
var excel_compare = require("excel-compare");

excel_compare({
    file1: '1.xlsx',
    file2: '2.xlsx',
    column_file1: {
        column: [1],
        join: ''
    },
    column_file2: {
        column: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        join: '-'
    }
})
```

Expected results :
a.xlsx

```
colab   colc    cold    cole    colf    colg
111     bbb     ccc     ddd     eee     22:00
123     xyx     tyu     lro     dmr     14:00:00 PM
431     xgh     chk     shd     dnj     14:00:00 PM
```

b.xlsx

```
colj    colab   colk    coll    colm    coln
ooj     111     mati    oop     ool     oom
cdf     123     mato    bdf     xdf     fgh
jjt     431     maty    bbn     rrr     lkj
```

output excel (c.xlsx)

```
colab colj colk col colm coln colc cold cole colf colg
 111  ooj  mati oop ool  oom  bbb  ccc  ddd eee   22:00
 123  cdf  mato bdf xdf  fgh  xyx  tyu  lro dmr   14:00:00 PM
 431  jjt  maty bbn rrr  lkj  xgh  chk  shd dnj   14:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Anyone who can help with this???

Comment: I've only used the [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) module for working with Excel sheets in node. You could use that one to do the join in node manually (search for the same `colab` value). From the Readme of your mentioned module, I wouldn't know what it really does and if it was what you want

Comment: @Narigo I want to match two coloumns from two different excel and then get the value of other cloumns according to that and create a new updated excel out of those two.
Can you explain what you are saying with xlsx I can give a try.

Comment: Sure, but is the module (that you wanted to work with) able to do that? I would try to use a different module and see how far you can get with another one.

Comment: I am pretty new to nodejs .. so not aware much of how to use the modules according to functionality the module I meantioned I have worked with is the one which I have searched and got , if you can help and guide here how to proceed